# How to handle parameterized SQLite query with lot of parameters Phonegap

Tags: sqlite, cordova

I'm wondering if someone could suggest me a smarter way to handle SQLite query with lot of parameters (up to 20+ fields).

Nowadays, I'm coding something like example below. Its a headache if I place parameter in the wrong order. I think the query should be a one time thing to  which needs to be built carefully. I'm okay if you said that. But if someone (or me) modify the query (add/remove) parameter, it should take sometime to review the parameter order carefully again and again.

```
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO some_table 
VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', [a, b, c, ...., z], , function(tx, res) {
/* Some code here */
}
```

Could someone suggest or recommend me the practical way to handle these parameters and make it more readable and make it easy to maintain the code?

Answer (score 0):

SQLite allows [different parameter placeholders](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#varparam); with a `:`, `@`, or `$` prefix, parameters can have a name.

It would be possible to write your own wrapper for `executeSql` that examines the SQL string, extracts the parameter names, and constructs a parameter array with the values of the variables with the same name:

```
myExecuteSQL('INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES(:a, :b, :c)')
```

The Tcl SQLite wrapper does it this way.
However, I do not know of any JavaScript implementation.